# How to apply color filter on live PreviewView of CameraX?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I want to apply color filters on camera preview. Is it possible to do with PreviewView of CameraX? If yes then how can I achieve that?

I'm using following properties:

```
androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha02 
androidx.camera:camera-core:1.1.0-alpha02
androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha02
```

Comment: Hi I am not sure it will help you or not have you tried to capture request builder?
builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_MONO);

Comment: Ok, I want to add color filters like we add to imageView.

Comment: The above code will add a color filter to your preview.

Comment: CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilderLeft;
captureRequestBuilderLeft = csiDeviceLeft.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

 builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_MONO);
 captureRequestBuilderLeft.addTarget(surface); //Add your surface view here

Comment: Cool.. Can I set color matrix to it?

Comment: Hi for color matrix there are some specif color params in this method. I am not sure how to do this but by providing different color codes you can change color filtrs.

Comment: @PratikPitale how did you achieve this?